Next.js Parallel Routes with WebPack
I am using parallel routes in my Next.js application. I have a dashboard, which consists of header and content, thus the directory structure:
Dashboard

@header

loading.tsx
page.tsx


@content

loading.tsx
page.tsx



I am building the app using webpack, and when I am getting following error when accessing the dashboard page:
Chunk Load Error: 
Loading chunk 6635 failed. (404) *** dashboard/%40header/loading-eacb3abac99bee42.js

I am looking for an advice how to configure WebPack, so that it works with parallel routing.
I am building the app in standalone setup for docker container.
